# Getting error while reading XML with OPENXML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, openxml

I am reading XML data using OPENXML in a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012.

My XML:

```
<name>
    <name>Temp1</name>
    <data>
        <mealID>5</mealID>
        <food>
            <foodID>11</foodID>
        </food>
        <food>
            <foodID>12</foodID>
        </food>
    </data>
    <data>
        <mealID>6</mealID>
        <food>
           <foodID>13</foodID>
        </food>
    </data>
</name>
```

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Insert_EatingProgramTemplate] 
    @Template xml,
    @intOutSuccess nvarchar(10) OUTPUT,
    @ErrorSeverity nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT,
    @ErrorMesg nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idoc int

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @ErrorSeverity = ''
    SET @ErrorMesg = ''
    SET @intOutSuccess = ''

    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT *
         FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/ROOT/Customer',1)
         WITH (CustomerID  varchar(10),
               ContactName varchar(20))
        SET @intOutSuccess = 1
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()  
        SET @ErrorMesg = ERROR_MESSAGE() 
        SET @intOutSuccess = -1
        GOTO A
    END CATCH
A:
    END
GO
```

While executing this procedure I am getting this error:

> Could not find prepared statement with handle 0

Any help, why I am getting this error?

Comment: Well, did you do any debugging? Like do you expect a certain value for `@idoc`? Did you output it to see if it contained the value you expected? Also, did you consider just querying the XML directly instead of using OPENXML, sp_xml_preparedocument, etc.?

Comment: yes i tried it with XML directly but getting error. I did not do any debugging for this

Comment: @Twix your OPENXML query completely unrelated to the XML structure you have. What values do you actually want to get from that XML sample? Anyway, I'd suggest to look into [`nodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) XML function instead

Comment: Just curious, what is the point of putting a goto in there? Also, you shouldn't use the sp_ prefix for procedure names. Here is a link to an article by @AaronBertrand http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: @har07 I know I have provided different select statement but that is what I tried on different XML and I could not relate it with my XML and don't know how to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to set `@idoc` by calling `sp_xml_preparedocument`, for example :

```sql
declare @template xml = '<name>
    <name>Temp1</name>
    <data>
        <mealID>5</mealID>
        <food>
            <foodID>11</foodID>
        </food>
        <food>
            <foodID>12</foodID>
        </food>
    </data>
    <data>
        <mealID>6</mealID>
        <food>
           <foodID>13</foodID>
        </food>
    </data>
</name>'
DECLARE @idoc int
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @template; 

SELECT *
     FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/name/data/food/foodID',1)
     WITH (FoodID  INT '.',
           MealID INT '../../mealID')

--clear parsed XML document from SQL Server cache
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc;
```

You can also achieve the same output by querying the xml variable directly :

```sql
SELECT 
    x.value('.', 'int') as FoodID
    , x.value('../../mealID[1]', 'int') as MealID
FROM @template.nodes('/name/data/food/foodID') as T(X)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also apply `sp_xml_removedocument` if you use `sp_xml_preparedocument`?

Comment: @AndriyM thanks for the hints, I didn't know initially, but [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190353.aspx) suggests that I should